# Convert object js display

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

For example i have object js

```
data = {"dt1_a": 20, "dt1_b": 30, "dt2_a": 40, "dt2_b": 50}
```

I want convert data to

```
data1 = {"dt1": {"a": 20, "b": 30}, "dt2": {"a": 40, "b": 50}}
```

Please suggest a specific solution.

Comment: First make algorithm: 1)Take all json data 2)Find common characters in multiple jsons ,and group them.3)Take common elementsm,and rest characters are put in to other side Removing "_" .

Answer (score 5):

Try something like

```
var data1 = {};
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    var parts = key.split('_'),
        p1 = parts[0];
    if (!data1[p1]) {
        data1[p1] = {};
    }
    data1[p1][parts[1]] = value;
})
console.log(data1)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3Vkcc/)

Answer (score 5):

Grab the object keys and loop through them, then apply the correct properties to the new object.

```
data = {"dt1_a": 20, "dt1_b": 30, "dt2_a": 40, "dt2_b": 50};
var data1 = {};
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){
   var keySplit = key.split("_");
   //create dt1, dt2 properties if they do not exist yet
   data1[keySplit[0]] = data1[keySplit[0]] || {};
   data1[keySplit[0]][keySplit[1]] = data[key]
});
```

Note this is reliant on the browser supporting `forEach` if the browser does not have it a [polyfill can be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)

You could also use for..in as Joseph Marikle mentions in the comments, which is also more compatible

```
for(key in data){
   var keySplit = key.split("_");
   //create dt1, dt2 properties if they do not exist yet
   data1[keySplit[0]] = data1[keySplit[0]] || {};
   data1[keySplit[0]][keySplit[1]] = data[key]
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel stupid for mistaking `forEach` for jQuery's `.each()` method (I removed my comment), but now I'm very curious,  What are the advantages of `forEach` over `for(i in obj)` syntax?

Comment: @JosephMarikle, actually probably none, as for...in is more compatible so probably should go with it. I just tend to think `Object.keys(obj)` when thinking of looping over object keys for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well `@Arun P Johny` & `@Patrick Evans` have covered the best possible ways. I would like to share one more answer which would be like re-wording the above two in simple terms.

```
var final = {};
$.each(data, function (index, value) {

    var arr = index.split('_'),
        name = arr[0],
        val = arr[1];

    if (final[name]) {
        final[name][val] = value;
    } else {
        final[name] = {};
        final[name][val] = value;
    }

});
console.log(final);
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/EWeGp/13/)